# Установить шрифт в пунктах в редактируемом div

Tags: javascript, шрифты

Вводные данные: имеется div элемент, есть выпадающий список с выбором размера шрифта.
Что хочется получить: Выделив на панели редактирования текст, используя выпадающий список задать размер шрифта.
Что сделано:

```js
function SetFontSizeOnPt(fontSize){
  var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  console.log(selection);//need on debug______________________________________________________________
  if(selection.startContainer!=selection.endContainer){
    console.log('many containers');//need on debug______________________________________________________________
    console.log(GetParentParagraph(selection.startContainer.parentElement));//need on debug______________________________________________________________
    console.log(GetParentParagraph(selection.endContainer.parentElement));//need on debug______________________________________________________________
    if(GetParentParagraph(selection.startContainer.parentElement)!=GetParentParagraph(selection.endContainer.parentElement)){
      console.log('many paragraphs');;//need on debug______________________________________________________________
      var elem = selection.startContainer.parentElement;      
      setFontSizeStart(elem, fontSize, selection.startOffset);
      var par =GetParentParagraph(selection.startContainer.parentElement);
      setFontSizeStart(par);
      
    }else{      
      var elem = selection.startContainer.parentElement;
      setFontSizeStart(elem, fontSize, selection.startOffset);
      elem = elem.nextSibling;
      while(elem!=selection.endContainer.parentElement){
        setFontSize(elem, fontSize);
        elem = elem.nextSibling;
        console.log(elem);;//need on debug______________________________________________________________
      }
      
      setFontSizeEnd(selection.endOffset, elem, fontSize);
    }
  }else{
    //console.log('one container');//need on debug______________________________________________________________
    setFontSizeOnlyOneContainer(selection.startContainer, fontSize, selection.startOffset, selection.endOffset);
  }
}

function setFontSizeOnlyOneContainer(element, fontSize, startOffset, endOffset){
  var osts =document.createTextNode(element.textContent.substring(0,startOffset));
  var spst =CreateSpan(element.textContent.substring(startOffset,endOffset),fontSize);
  var oste =document.createTextNode(element.textContent.substring(endOffset));
  element.textContent='';
  element.parentElement.appendChild(osts);
  element.parentElement.appendChild(spst);
  element.parentElement.appendChild(oste);
}//for text in only one 

function setFontSizeStart(elementE, fontSize, startOffset){
  if(startOffset==0){
    setFontSize(elementE, fontSize);
  }else{
    if(elementE.children&&elementE.children.length>0){
      setFontSizeStart(elementE.children[0], fontSize, startOffset);
      for(var i=1;i<elementE.children.length;i++){
        setFontSize(elementE.children[i], fontSize);
      }
    }else{
      var ost =document.createTextNode(elementE.textContent.substring(0,startOffset));
      var spst =CreateSpan(elementE.textContent.substring(startOffset),fontSize);   
      elementE.textContent='';
      elementE.parentElement.appendChild(ost);
      elementE.parentElement.appendChild( spst);
    }
  }
}//first container

function setFontSize(element, fontSize){
 if(HasSpanElement(element)){
  if(element.children.length<1){
   element.style.fontSize=fontSize+'pt';
  }else{
   for(var i=0;i<element.children.length;i++){
    if(HasSpanElement(element.children[i])){
     if(isElementSPAN(element.children[i])){
      if(element.children[i].children.length>0){
       element.children[i].style.fontSize=fontSize+'pt';
       for(var j=0;j<element.children[i].children.length;j++){
        setFontSize(element.children[i].children[j], fontSize);
       }
      }else{
       element.children[i].style.fontSize=fontSize+'pt';
      }
     }else{
      setFontSize(element.children[i], fontSize);
     }   
    }else{
     setFontSize(element.children[i], fontSize);
    }
   }
  }   
 }else{
    if(element!=null){
      if(element.children&&element.children.length>0){
   for(var i=0;i<element.children.length;i++){
    setFontSize(element.children[i], fontSize);
        console.log(element.children[i]);//need on debug______________________________________________________________
   }
  }else{
   var span= CreateSpan(element.textContent, fontSize);
      console.log(span);//need on debug______________________________________________________________
   element.textContent='';
   element.parentElement.appendChild(span);
  }
    }
  
 }
}//all elements

function setFontSizeEnd(endOffset,element, fontSize){
  var textLength=element.textContent.length;
  if(textLength!=endOffset){    
      var ost =document.createTextNode(element.textContent.substring(endOffset));
      var spst =CreateSpan(element.textContent.substring(0,endOffset),fontSize);   
      element.textContent='';      
      element.parentElement.appendChild( spst);
      element.parentElement.appendChild(ost);
  }else{
    setFontSize(element, fontSize);
  }
  
}//last container

function HasSpanElement(element){
  var res = isElementSPAN(element);
  if(element!=null&&element.children&&element.children.length>0){
     for(var i=0;i<element.children.length;i++){
       res= res||isElementSPAN(element.children[i]) || HasSpanElement(element.children[i]);
     }
    }
  return res;
}

function CreateSpan(text, fs){
  var sp=document.createElement("span");
    sp.style.fontSize=fs+'pt';
    sp.innerHTML=text;
  return sp;
}

function isElementSPAN(element){
  var res = false;
  try{
    res = element.tagName=='SPAN';
  }catch{}
  return res;
}

function GetParentParagraph(element){
 // console.log('who find');
  //console.log(element);
  var res =element;    
  if(element.tagName){
    if(element.tagName!='P'){
      //console.log('wehre find');
     // console.log(element.parentElement);
      res = GetParentParagraph(element.parentElement);
      
    }
  }else{
    res = GetParentParagraph(element.parentElement);
  } 
  return res;
}

function ContainsChild(parentE, child){
  var res = parentE==child;  
  if(!res&&parentE.children){
    for(var i=0; i<parentE.children.length;i++){
      res=res||ContainsChild(parentE.children[i],child);
      if(res){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return res;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>
<select name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl27" style="width:50px;" onchange="SetFontSizeOnPt(this.value)">
       
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="11">11</option>
       <option selected="selected" value="12">12</option>
       <option value="14">14</option>
       <option value="16">16</option>
       <option value="18">18</option>
       <option value="20">20</option>
       <option value="22">22</option>
       <option value="24">24</option>
       <option value="26">26</option>
       <option value="28">28</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
       <option value="36">36</option>
       <option value="48">48</option>
       <option value="72">72</option>

      </select>
</div>
<div onclick="document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;height:955px;width:615px;" contenteditable="true">
Некоторый текст, размером шрифта которого хочется управлять.
</div>
</div>
```

В итоге совсем запутался, и не могу понять, почему при повторном выделении текста и смене шрифта, получается какаято ерунда. Может есть готовое решение и я зря парюсь, или может кто найдет мою ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось долго мучатся, но в итоге не без багов, но работает следующий код:

```js
function SetFontSizeOnPt(fontSize){
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var firstParagraph=getParentParagraph(selection.commonAncestorContainer, selection.startContainer);
  
    if(firstParagraph!=null){    
        if(firstParagraph.textContent.trim()==selection.toString().trim()){      
            setFSParagraph(firstParagraph, fontSize);
        }else{
            setFSParagraphs(selection, fontSize)
        }
    }else{   
        alert('Неправильно сформирован документ, попробуйте перезагрузить страницу!');
    }
}

function getParentParagraph(MaxParent, element){
    var res = null;   
    var node;
    for (node = element; node; node = node.parentNode){     
        if (node == MaxParent){
            if(isElementParagraph(node)){
                res=node;
            }            
            break;
        }else{         
            if(isElementParagraph(node)){
                res=node;        
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
    if(res==null){
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
            node = node.parentNode
            if(isElementParagraph(node)){
                res=node;        
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function removeFSInSpan(element){
    if(isElementSPAN(element)){
        element.style.fontSize='';     
    }
    removeStyle(element);
    if(element.children.length){     
        for(var i=0;i<element.children.length;i++)
            try{      
                removeFSInSpan(element.children[i])
            }catch{
        
            }
    }   
}

function removeStyle(element){
    try{
        if(element.style.length==0){
            element.removeAttribute('style');
        }   
        var ena =!element.hasAttributes();
        if(isElementSPAN(element)&&ena){      
            var ostn =document.createTextNode(element.textContent);
            element.parentElement.insertBefore(ostn,element);
            element.remove();
        }
    
    }catch{}
}

function setFSParagraph(par, fontSize){
    removeFSInSpan(par);
    par.style.fontSize=fontSize+'pt';  
}

function getNextNode(node){
    if (node.firstChild)
        return node.firstChild;
    while (node){
        if (node.nextSibling)
            return node.nextSibling;
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}

function getNodesInRange(range){
    var start = range.startContainer;
    var end = range.endContainer;
    var commonAncestor = range.commonAncestorContainer;
    var nodes = [];
    var node;  
    for (node = start; node; node = getNextNode(node)){
        nodes.push(node);
        if (node == end)
            break;
    }
    return nodes;
}

function getTextContainersInRange(range){
    var res=[];
    var arrR=getNodesInRange(range);
    for(var i=0;i<arrR.length;i++){
        if(arrR[i].nodeName=='#text' && arrR[i].textContent.length>0){       
            res.push(arrR[i]);
        }      
    }
    return res;
}

function getParagraphsInRange(range){  
    var res=[];
    var fp =getParentParagraph(range.commonAncestorContainer, range.startContainer);  
    if(fp!=null){
        res.push(fp);
    }
    var arrR=getNodesInRange(range);
    for(var i=0;i<arrR.length;i++){
        if(isElementParagraph(arrR[i])){
            res.push(arrR[i]);
        }
    }
  
    return res;
  
}

function CreateSpan(text, fs){
    var sp=document.createElement('span');
    sp.style.fontSize=fs+'pt';
    sp.innerHTML=text;
    return sp;
}

function isElementSPAN(element){
    var res = false;
    try{
        res = element.tagName=='SPAN';
    }catch{}
    return res;
}


function isElementParagraph(element){
  var res = false;
  try{
    res = element.tagName=='P';
  }catch{}
  return res;
}

function setFSParagraphs(range, fontSize){
    var phs = getParagraphsInRange(range);
    for(var i in phs){
        if(i==0){
            if(phs.length==1){
                setFSToContainers(getTextContainersInParagraph(range, phs[0]), fontSize, range.startOffset, range.endOffset);
            }else{
                setFSToContainers(getTextContainersInParagraph(range, phs[0]), fontSize, range.startOffset, null);
            }
        }else if(i==phs.length-1){
            setFSToContainers(getTextContainersInParagraph(range, phs[i]), fontSize, null, range.endOffset);
        }else{
            setFSParagraph(phs[i], fontSize);
        }
    }
  
}

function getTextContainersInParagraph(range, par){
    var res=[];
    var tc =getTextContainersInRange(range);
    for(var i in tc){
        if(getParentParagraph(range.commonAncestorContainer,tc[i])==par){
            res.push(tc[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function setFSToContainers(containers, fontSize, startOffset, endOffset ){
    for(var i in containers){
        if(i==0){
            if(containers.length==1){
                setFSWithOffsetContainer(containers[0], fontSize, startOffset, endOffset);
            }else{
                setFSWithOffsetContainer(containers[0], fontSize, startOffset, null);
            }     
        }else if(i==containers.length-1){
            setFSWithOffsetContainer(containers[i], fontSize, null, endOffset);
        }else{
            setFSToAllContainer(containers[i], fontSize);
        }  
    }
}

function setFSToAllContainer(container, fontSize){
    if(isElementSPAN(container.parentNode)){
        container.parentNode.style.fontSize= fontSize+'pt';
    }else{
        var sp=CreateSpan(container.textContent,fontSize);
        container.parentElement.insertBefore(sp,container);
        removetextContentContainer(container);
    
    }
}

function setFSWithOffsetContainer(container, fontSize, startOffset, endOffset){
    if(startOffset==null){
        startOffset=0;
    }
    if(endOffset==null){
        endOffset=container.textContent.length;
    }
    if(startOffset==0&&endOffset==container.textContent.length){
        setFSToAllContainer(container, fontSize);
    }else{
        if(startOffset==0){
            var spst =CreateSpan(container.textContent.substring(startOffset, endOffset),fontSize);     
            var ostk=document.createTextNode(container.textContent.substring(endOffset));
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(ostk,container);
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(spst,ostk);   
            removetextContentContainer(container);
        }else if(endOffset==container.textContent.length){
            var ostn =document.createTextNode(container.textContent.substring(0,startOffset));    
            var spst =CreateSpan(container.textContent.substring(startOffset),fontSize);
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(spst,container);      
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(ostn,spst);
            removetextContentContainer(container);
        }else{
            var ostn =document.createTextNode(container.textContent.substring(0,startOffset));    
            var spst =CreateSpan(container.textContent.substring(startOffset, endOffset),fontSize);     
            var ostk=document.createTextNode(container.textContent.substring(endOffset));
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(ostk,container);
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(spst,ostk);
            container.parentElement.insertBefore(ostn,spst);
            removetextContentContainer(container);
        }
    } 
}

function removetextContentContainer(element){
    try{
        element.textContent=null;
        if(elem.nodeName=='#text'){         
            element.remove();//it need thats no null text element        
        }
    }catch{}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;">
      <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl21" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAASCAIAAADQR7l6AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAAEBJREFUOE/NzjEKADAMQtHc/9BSEIeAS2iL5M0m/MKzhS9qTAeUrdDIZCs6HVC2QiOTreh0QNkKjczvijsbXgAHrA7EluvsGqwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" onclick="document.execCommand('justifyLeft', false, null);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl21&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl22" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAASCAYAAABB7B6eAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwQAADsEBuJFr7QAAAHJJREFUOE+90sEKACEIBND5/082y/USSM1CLDsdXnjRUQhjjFBC7z2U7gcA+GSdM924wLPYsS0Z1lvpf5G7R8W2PLHOmbaAv70GsC0Z1ltlQMtCB96yKNiWJ9Y5E1o+Sq8BbEuG9VYXLjALJVg+SuIAiwcu/NVwkiNN8QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" onclick="document.execCommand('justifyCenter', false, null);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl22&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl23" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAASCAYAAABB7B6eAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwQAADsEBuJFr7QAAAG1JREFUOE/F0UEKwDAIRNG5/5GNiXUdPkWK0sULIugI0TknJmnvHZP+CZD0Ce6iZqcM8Cze0bUEZ+nnO8nd40bXVeAuanYqBdC1BGfdVxZz5CuLC11XgbtWPpNKAXQtwVlqdtIyi0myfCYNB1g8RlbVcMs64pIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" onclick="document.execCommand('justifyRight', false, null);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl23&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl24" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAASCAYAAABfJS4tAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwQAADsEBuJFr7QAAAGpJREFUOE+90TEKADEIRNG5/5HVxLXbEC1kcbZ4QSw+QrD3dgastZzhvzCAT1LnXkyJsMXwqq7pSJ3qRyfAzPxUXdOROvdiCvNijWEeTGM4VNd0pI7Gw5DC1TUdqXMvpkBFnAESDwMpLP4AZn4j3jFzdV0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" onclick="document.execCommand('justifyFull', false, null);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl24&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))">
     </div><div style="display:inline-block;">
      <select name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl26" onchange="document.execCommand('fontName', false, this.value); return false;">
       <option value="Aharoni">Aharoni</option>
       <option value="Aldhabi">Aldhabi</option>
       <option value="Andalus">Andalus</option>
       <option value="Angsana New">Angsana New</option>
       <option value="AngsanaUPC">AngsanaUPC</option>
       <option value="Aparajita">Aparajita</option>
       <option value="Arabic Typesetting">Arabic Typesetting</option>
       <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
       <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
       <option value="Arial Unicode MS">Arial Unicode MS</option>
       <option value="Batang">Batang</option>
       <option value="BatangChe">BatangChe</option>
       <option value="Book Antiqua">Book Antiqua</option>
       <option value="Browallia New">Browallia New</option>
       <option value="BrowalliaUPC">BrowalliaUPC</option>
       <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
       <option value="Calibri Light">Calibri Light</option>
       <option value="Cambria">Cambria</option>
       <option value="Cambria Math">Cambria Math</option>
       <option value="Candara">Candara</option>
       <option value="Century">Century</option>
       <option value="Century Gothic">Century Gothic</option>
       <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
       <option value="Consolas">Consolas</option>
       <option value="Constantia">Constantia</option>
       <option value="Corbel">Corbel</option>
       <option value="Cordia New">Cordia New</option>
       <option value="CordiaUPC">CordiaUPC</option>
       <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
       <option value="DaunPenh">DaunPenh</option>
       <option value="David">David</option>
       <option value="DengXian">DengXian</option>
       <option value="DFKai-SB">DFKai-SB</option>
       <option value="DilleniaUPC">DilleniaUPC</option>
       <option value="DokChampa">DokChampa</option>
       <option value="Dotum">Dotum</option>
       <option value="DotumChe">DotumChe</option>
       <option value="Ebrima">Ebrima</option>
       <option value="Estrangelo Edessa">Estrangelo Edessa</option>
       <option value="EucrosiaUPC">EucrosiaUPC</option>
       <option value="Euphemia">Euphemia</option>
       <option value="FangSong">FangSong</option>
       <option value="Franklin Gothic Medium">Franklin Gothic Medium</option>
       <option value="FrankRuehl">FrankRuehl</option>
       <option value="FreesiaUPC">FreesiaUPC</option>
       <option value="Gabriola">Gabriola</option>
       <option value="Gadugi">Gadugi</option>
       <option value="Gautami">Gautami</option>
       <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
       <option value="Gisha">Gisha</option>
       <option value="Gulim">Gulim</option>
       <option value="GulimChe">GulimChe</option>
       <option value="Gungsuh">Gungsuh</option>
       <option value="GungsuhChe">GungsuhChe</option>
       <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
       <option value="IrisUPC">IrisUPC</option>
       <option value="Iskoola Pota">Iskoola Pota</option>
       <option value="JasmineUPC">JasmineUPC</option>
       <option value="Javanese Text">Javanese Text</option>
       <option value="KaiTi">KaiTi</option>
       <option value="Kalinga">Kalinga</option>
       <option value="Kartika">Kartika</option>
       <option value="Khmer UI">Khmer UI</option>
       <option value="KodchiangUPC">KodchiangUPC</option>
       <option value="Kokila">Kokila</option>
       <option value="Lao UI">Lao UI</option>
       <option value="Latha">Latha</option>
       <option value="Leelawadee">Leelawadee</option>
       <option value="Leelawadee UI">Leelawadee UI</option>
       <option value="Leelawadee UI Semilight">Leelawadee UI Semilight</option>
       <option value="Levenim MT">Levenim MT</option>
       <option value="LilyUPC">LilyUPC</option>
       <option value="Lucida Console">Lucida Console</option>
       <option value="Lucida Sans Unicode">Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
       <option value="Malgun Gothic">Malgun Gothic</option>
       <option value="Mangal">Mangal</option>
       <option value="Marlett">Marlett</option>
       <option value="Meiryo">Meiryo</option>
       <option value="Meiryo UI">Meiryo UI</option>
       <option value="Microsoft Himalaya">Microsoft Himalaya</option>
       <option value="Microsoft JhengHei">Microsoft JhengHei</option>
       <option value="Microsoft JhengHei Light">Microsoft JhengHei Light</option>
       <option value="Microsoft JhengHei UI">Microsoft JhengHei UI</option>
       <option value="Microsoft JhengHei UI Light">Microsoft JhengHei UI Light</option>
       <option value="Microsoft MHei">Microsoft MHei</option>
       <option value="Microsoft NeoGothic">Microsoft NeoGothic</option>
       <option value="Microsoft New Tai Lue">Microsoft New Tai Lue</option>
       <option value="Microsoft PhagsPa">Microsoft PhagsPa</option>
       <option value="Microsoft Sans Serif">Microsoft Sans Serif</option>
       <option value="Microsoft Tai Le">Microsoft Tai Le</option>
       <option value="Microsoft Uighur">Microsoft Uighur</option>
       <option value="Microsoft YaHei">Microsoft YaHei</option>
       <option value="Microsoft YaHei Light">Microsoft YaHei Light</option>
       <option value="Microsoft YaHei UI">Microsoft YaHei UI</option>
       <option value="Microsoft YaHei UI Light">Microsoft YaHei UI Light</option>
       <option value="Microsoft Yi Baiti">Microsoft Yi Baiti</option>
       <option value="MingLiU">MingLiU</option>
       <option value="MingLiU-ExtB">MingLiU-ExtB</option>
       <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS">MingLiU_HKSCS</option>
       <option value="MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB">MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB</option>
       <option value="Miriam">Miriam</option>
       <option value="Miriam Fixed">Miriam Fixed</option>
       <option value="Mongolian Baiti">Mongolian Baiti</option>
       <option value="MoolBoran">MoolBoran</option>
       <option value="MS Gothic">MS Gothic</option>
       <option value="MS Mincho">MS Mincho</option>
       <option value="MS PGothic">MS PGothic</option>
       <option value="MS PMincho">MS PMincho</option>
       <option value="MS UI Gothic">MS UI Gothic</option>
       <option value="MT Extra">MT Extra</option>
       <option value="MV Boli">MV Boli</option>
       <option value="Myanmar Text">Myanmar Text</option>
       <option value="Narkisim">Narkisim</option>
       <option value="Nirmala UI">Nirmala UI</option>
       <option value="Nirmala UI Semilight">Nirmala UI Semilight</option>
       <option value="NSimSun">NSimSun</option>
       <option value="Nyala">Nyala</option>
       <option value="Palatino Linotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
       <option value="Plantagenet Cherokee">Plantagenet Cherokee</option>
       <option value="PMingLiU">PMingLiU</option>
       <option value="PMingLiU-ExtB">PMingLiU-ExtB</option>
       <option value="Raavi">Raavi</option>
       <option value="Rod">Rod</option>
       <option value="Sakkal Majalla">Sakkal Majalla</option>
       <option value="Segoe Print">Segoe Print</option>
       <option value="Segoe Script">Segoe Script</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Black">Segoe UI Black</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Emoji">Segoe UI Emoji</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Light">Segoe UI Light</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Semibold">Segoe UI Semibold</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Semilight">Segoe UI Semilight</option>
       <option value="Segoe UI Symbol">Segoe UI Symbol</option>
       <option value="Segoe WP">Segoe WP</option>
       <option value="Segoe WP Black">Segoe WP Black</option>
       <option value="Segoe WP Light">Segoe WP Light</option>
       <option value="Segoe WP Semibold">Segoe WP Semibold</option>
       <option value="Segoe WP SemiLight">Segoe WP SemiLight</option>
       <option value="Shonar Bangla">Shonar Bangla</option>
       <option value="Shruti">Shruti</option>
       <option value="SimHei">SimHei</option>
       <option value="Simplified Arabic">Simplified Arabic</option>
       <option value="Simplified Arabic Fixed">Simplified Arabic Fixed</option>
       <option value="SimSun">SimSun</option>
       <option value="SimSun-ExtB">SimSun-ExtB</option>
       <option value="Sitka Banner">Sitka Banner</option>
       <option value="Sitka Display">Sitka Display</option>
       <option value="Sitka Heading">Sitka Heading</option>
       <option value="Sitka Small">Sitka Small</option>
       <option value="Sitka Subheading">Sitka Subheading</option>
       <option value="Sitka Text">Sitka Text</option>
       <option value="Sylfaen">Sylfaen</option>
       <option value="Symbol">Symbol</option>
       <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
       <option selected="selected" value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
       <option value="Traditional Arabic">Traditional Arabic</option>
       <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
       <option value="Tunga">Tunga</option>
       <option value="Urdu Typesetting">Urdu Typesetting</option>
       <option value="Utsaah">Utsaah</option>
       <option value="Vani">Vani</option>
       <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
       <option value="Vijaya">Vijaya</option>
       <option value="Vrinda">Vrinda</option>
       <option value="Webdings">Webdings</option>
       <option value="Wingdings">Wingdings</option>
       <option value="Wingdings 2">Wingdings 2</option>
       <option value="Wingdings 3">Wingdings 3</option>
       <option value="Yu Gothic">Yu Gothic</option>
       <option value="Yu Gothic Light">Yu Gothic Light</option>
       <option value="Yu Mincho">Yu Mincho</option>
       <option value="Yu Mincho Demibold">Yu Mincho Demibold</option>
       <option value="Yu Mincho Light">Yu Mincho Light</option>

      </select><select name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl27" onchange="SetFontSizeOnPt(this.value); return false;" style="width:50px;">       
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="11">11</option>
       <option selected="selected" value="12">12</option>
       <option value="14">14</option>
       <option value="16">16</option>
       <option value="18">18</option>
       <option value="20">20</option>
       <option value="22">22</option>
       <option value="24">24</option>
       <option value="26">26</option>
       <option value="28">28</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
       <option value="36">36</option>
       <option value="48">48</option>
       <option value="72">72</option>

      </select><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl28" src="" alt=" Ж " onclick=" document.execCommand('bold', false, null); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl28&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="font-weight:bold;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl29" src="" alt=" К " onclick=" document.execCommand('italic', false, null); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl29&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;"><input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl30" src="" alt=" Ч " onclick=" document.execCommand('underline', false, null); return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl30&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;"><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">&nbsp;Цвет текста: <input name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl32" type="color" onchange="parentElement.style.color =this.value; document.execCommand('foreColor', false, this.value); return false;"></span>
     </div><div>
      Строк: <input name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl34" type="number"> Столбцов: <input name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl35" type="number"><input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl36" value="Добавить таблицу" onclick="SetTable(this);return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl26$g_928efcde_cbfd_4a87_9bb5_b96667372f12$ctl36&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))">
     </div>
    </div><div onclick="document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;height:955px;width:615px;" contenteditable="true"><p align="justify">

    Тестирование работы с текстом.</p><p align="justify">Данный <b>текст</b> <u>предназначен</u> для <i>редактирования</i>, в нем может быть различное выравнивание, например:</p><p align="left">слева</p><p align="center">по центру <br></p><p align="right">справа.</p><p align="justify">Кроме того данный текст предполагает изменение его цвета: <font color="#ff0000">красный</font>, <font color="#0000ff">синий</font> и<font color="#008000"> зеленый</font>. <br></p><p align="justify">Но <span style="font-size: 12pt;">этого мало</span> <span style="font-size: 18pt;">и <span style="font-size: 24pt;"></span></span><span style="font-size: 24pt;">я захотел вывести различные размеры шрифта в пунктах, но именно в этом вопросе столкнулся с проблемой - функция которая отвечает за такое поведение</span> <font color="#ff0000"><u><i><b>по умолчанию, отсутствует.</b></i></u></font> Поэтому, при помощи <u>лома</u> и <u>такой-то матери</u> пришлось<i> танцевать с бубном</i>, что <b>дало результат,</b> хотя есть и некоторые баги.<br></p></div>
   </div>
```

В общем кому понадобится, берите, ноне забывайте плюсовать карму)))